# Клиент не смог обработать запрос обратного вызова в связи с внутренней ошибкой

Tags: c#, wcf

Помогите пожалуйста устранить ошибку при вызове функции контракта обратного вызова с сервера. Ошибка такая: "Клиент не смог обработать запрос обратного вызова в связи с внутренней ошибкой. Для получения дополнительных сведений об ошибке либо включите IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (с помощью атрибута CallbackBehaviorAttribute или через поведение ) на клиенте для того чтобы выслать информацию об исключении назад серверу, или включить трассировку согласно инструкции Microsoft .NET Framework SDK и проверить записи журнала трассировки клиента." Кода много и код функции в которой возникает ошибка вам ничего не скажет, поэтому я просто дам ссылку на свой репозиторий: https://github.com/DarkByte2015/lab3.

P.S. Если будете искать по коду - ошибка возникает в классе ClientView в функции Calculate.

Comment: Добавьте в клиент обработку ошибок с записью в лог или на консоль. `try { ... } catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex); }`

Comment: Куда конкретно? Там есть обработка ошибок в Main.

Comment: В обработчик обратного вызова, очевидно же.

Comment: Да кажется что то начало проясняться. Выдало вот такую ошибку: [ссылка](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jlvw77lfypb9knz/2016-04-03_17-16-44.png?dl=0). Кажется у меня взаимоблокировка, я пока еще не научился их лечить. :( Reentrant у меня установлен у контракта сервиса, но судя по ошибке это не помогает. Пробовал еще у контракта обратного вызова на стороне клиента поставить, но тоже не помогло. Как быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как написано в исключении, поставьте задайте правильный CallbackBehavior *у реализации контракта обратного вызова*.

Comment: Вы дочитали мой коммент до конца? Я же написал что у меня стоит Reentrant и так у сервиса и не помогает.

Comment: @DarkByte извиняюсь, поправился.

Comment: Опять не дочитали до конца комент. Я же говорю я и контракта обратного вызова этот атрибут проставил, но не помогло это.

Comment: Нет, теперь вы не дочитали до конца ответ.

Comment: Что я не так сказал? "Пробовал еще у контракта обратного вызова на стороне клиента поставить, но тоже не помогло." - именно то что вы написали. Естественно у реализации, у интерфейса вообще нельзя проставить CallbackBehavior.

Comment: Упс, да извиняюсь перепутал ServiceBehavior и CallbackBehavior. Сейчас проставил этот атрибут. Теперь такая фигня: один клиент из двух запущенных вообще молчит, второй выводит вот что: [ссылка](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jdcuriqn2lqzp7s/2016-04-03_18-45-04.png?dl=0).

Comment: Дальше я уже стал отлаживать сервер. Возникло подозрение что клиентам не хватает задержки в одну секунду для решения, увеличил до 5 секунд. Теперь такая фигня: один из двух клиентов запущенных опять таки молчит почему то, зато второй делает всю работу, но в конце результат на сервере не выводится, а вместо этого выводится ошибка: "Очередь пуста.". Это довольно странно учитывая то что у меня везде где делается Deque из очереди стоят проверки, чтобы она не была пустой... Короче вопроса теперь два: почему молчит первый клиент и почему выскакивает эта ошибка?

Comment: Да кстати еще по поводу таймаутов: я то вон изощряюсь с таймером, но кажется в wpf же есть какие то встроенные средства для таких вещей? Как задать таймаут за который если не будет получен ответ от клиента (не будет вызвана функция SetResult) то будет ошибка и клиент будет отключен? Или это все таки так нельзя?

P.S. Видел просто какие то таймауты в конфиге задаются иногда.

Comment: Отлаживал отлаживал, никак вообще не пойму в чем проблема... Тупо один клиент сразу кикается где то, это даже в отладчик не попадает. Точку останова ставлю, но на нее не перескакивает, а потом смотрю и клиентов работающих уже на одного меньше... Точнее даже не на одного меньше а один, потому что тот первый он так и не добавился почему то... Я обновил репозиторий по ссылке в стартовом посте. Можете глянуть с изменениями.

Comment: помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Задайте отдельный вопрос.